# Linux авторан от имени пользователя

Tags: java, linux, autoload

Всем привет.

**суть проблемы.**

есть вот такая структура:

1. home/alex/app/app.jar (owner: alex/alex, mode: 0755)
2. home/alex/.cash/cfg (owner: alex/alex, mode: 0644)

при запуске app.jar этот должен джарник кормится файлом cfg в принципе все хорошо если запускать ручками с консоли ***java -jar app.jar***, а вот если идет автозапуск то app.jar не видит cfg. Автозапуск настроен через **script.sh** (owner: alex/alex, mode: 0755) и **update-rc.d** вот описание [так](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) и [так](https://losst.ru/avtozagruzka-servisov-v-ubuntu)

И вот здесь начинаются траблы такое чувство что Джава запускается от рута и app.jar тоже запускает от рута как я понимаю, вот что пишет

```
alex@ip:~$ ps -aux | grep app
root       808  8.6 17.4 2246144 175840 ?      Sl   17:01   0:07 java -Dbot.ablutelyPath=/home/alex/app -Xmx256M -jar /home/alex/app/app.jar /tmp
alex    1414  0.0  0.1  14856  1032 pts/0    S+   17:02   0:00 grep --color=to app
```

или может эта проблема в ***Dbot.ablutelyPath=/home/alex/app***

***Заранее благодарен за ответ!***

Comment: Все сервисы системы запускаются от рута. Права и владелец на .sh файле вообще ни на что не влияют. Хотите что бы выполнялось под пользователем, так и запускайте явно под нужным пользователем, с помощью sudo -u alex например

Comment: Пользователь загружается вместе с профилем и с переменной path . И тогда все хорошо у вас. Автозагрузка не знает ваш path. И не находит cfg.

Comment: для начала попробовать добавить в начало `sudo -u alex`. если не поможет, попроботвать после nohup. А вообще перед этим не помешало бы выполнить cd в ту папку в которой должно работать приложение

Comment: @Mike Ок. спс. попробую. 
PS. после nohup уже пробовал не стартует

Comment: @Mike СПАСИБО похоже что получилось (***добавить в начало sudo -u alex nohup java $SAMPLE_PROPERTIES $XMX -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &***)